# Determine if the function is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Determine whether the following is a linear transformation. Explain your answer by giving an appropriate proof or counterexample.

$S : P_2\longrightarrow P_3$ defined by $S(p(x)) = x\,p(x) + p'(x),$ where $p'(x)$ is the derivative of $p(x)$.

I know I have to prove it using that:

Let $K$ be a field, $V$ and $W$ be two $K$-vector spaces. The map $T:V\longrightarrow W$ is linear iff

$T(u+v) = T(u)+T(v),\ \forall\, u,v\in V$ and

$T(\alpha u) = \alpha T(u),\forall\, \alpha\in K,\forall u\in V.$

But I am unsure how to proceed with this particular question. Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take two polynomials $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $g(x)=ux^2+vx+w$ and compute

(1) $S(f(x)+g(x))$ and $S(f(x)) + S(g(x))$,

(2) $S(\alpha f(x))$ and $\alpha S(f(x))$ for scalar $\alpha$.

Use that

$f(x)+g(x) = (a+u)x^2+(b+v)x+(c+w)$,

$\alpha f(x) = (\alpha a)x^2 + (\alpha b)x+(\alpha c)$,

$f'(x) = (2a)x+b$.

Answer (score 1):

You can argument that $F\big(p(x)\big)=x\,p(x)$ and $G(p(x))=p^{\prime}(x)$ are linear transformations and the sum of two linear transformation is also linear.